# Finding modulus and argument of $\,z³ - 4\sqrt3 + 4i = 0$.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I think I am messing up somewhere as the principle argument should be a nice number from the standard triangles such as $\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $\frac{\pi}{6}$ or something close. (That's what we have mainly been working with)

I have made $z^3 = w$

So $w =4\sqrt3 - 4i$

$|w| = \sqrt{4\sqrt3^2+(-4i)^2}$

=$\sqrt{48-16}$

=$2\sqrt8$

$\theta$ (which I make the angle from the $x$ axis to the $|w|$ line in the complex plane) = $\tan^{-1}\frac{4\sqrt3}{-4}$

In this case it is less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so is the same as the principle argument or $\operatorname{Arg} z$ (not sure if my thinking is correct on this, it's just how I see it)

So I have a modulus of $2\sqrt8$, and a principle argument of $\tan^{-1}\frac{4\sqrt3}{-4}$which doesn't look right. Normally this would be a simple fraction with $\pi$ in it.

So $w = |w|e^{i(\operatorname{arg}z+2k\pi)}$

= $2\sqrt8e^{i(\tan^{-1}\frac{4\sqrt3}{-4}+2k\pi)}$

Since $z^3 = w$

$z = 2\sqrt8^\frac13e^{i\frac{(\tan^{-1}\frac{4\sqrt3}{-4}+2k\pi)}3}$

where $k = 0, 1, 2$

Can someone please let me know where I have gone wrong. Sorry about the small font, first time formatting. Cheers

Comment: Hey. $2 \sqrt(8) = 2 \sqrt{2^3} = 2 \sqrt {2^2*2}=4 \sqrt {2}$. Also, please edit your question and use mathjax/latex. It's easy and you can find out how in this [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Not all the angles are rational multiples of $\pi$. This one is, though. Hint: it comes from one of the two right angled triangles that every student **MUST** memorize. Not because me the teacher believes in memorizing things, but simply because they occur so frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in calculating the absolute value:
$$|w|=\sqrt{(4\sqrt3)^2+(-4)^2}=\sqrt{48+16}=\sqrt{64}=8.$$

The general rule is
$$
|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.
$$
Think of the absolute value as distance from the origin. The complex number $a+bi$ corresponds to the point $(a,b)$. The distance of the point $(a,b)$ from the origin is gotten from Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: There is also a mistake in computing θ which is $tan^{-1} \frac{4}{-4\sqrt3}$ or  $tan^{-1} \frac{1}{-\sqrt3}$

Comment: Ah thanks for that. Won't be making that mistake again.